# How do I get it to be redirected to login when http response has status 401 due to an expired signature of the token?

Tags: angular

The following code listens for http responses to an api that includes the 401 status because a token has expired. In the case that status 401 is given, it should redirect to login

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpErrorResponse,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import * as fromApp from "@app/system/store/app.reducers";
import * as loginActions from "@app/core/modules/login/store/auth.actions";

@Injectable()
export class AuthSignatureExpiredInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>,
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap(
                (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {},
                (err: any) => {
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        if (err.status === 401) {
                            this.store.dispatch(loginActions.logout());
                            this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The behavior that I experience is the following, if after the token has expired I refresh the browser then the user is properly redirected to the login page. But if I only move between the different internal links of the site I am not redirected, I must press f5 to force being sent to the login page

How can I ensure that this behavior also occurs when navigating between different links within the site?

How do I get it to be redirected to login when http response has status 401 due to an expired signature of the token?

Comment: When you navigate between pages, do you get a 401 on your requests?

Comment: Yes, this is content of `err`

`{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  },
  "status": 401,
  "statusText": "Unauthorized",
  "url": "http://localhost:3002/services/some/api/call/contacts?id.equals=168420",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:3002/services/some/api/call/contacts?customerId.equals=168420: 401 Unauthorized",
  "error": {
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
  }
}`

Comment: Looks good, write a `console.log(err)` before your `if` statement and see exactly what that `err` looks like

Answer (score 0):

Store the fact that the token has expired via your interceptor. Or remove the record from storage via the interceptor on 401 eg:

Create session record initially on intercept if authentication is valid, e.g:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('auth_token', myToken);
```

Then remove on intercept if not valid:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
```

Then you can use Angular route guards to control access per route by implementing [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface (or for all child routes with [CanActivateChild](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild)). See [Medium route guard article](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3) for how to set up a route guard which can check if the token does not exist or is expired.